# QRCode stored inforamtion is not decoded using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I am trying to write a program in python to detect QR code from image.

```
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread('sample1.png')

det = cv.QRCodeDetector()
decodedText, points, _ = det.detectAndDecode(im)
                
if  points is not None:
    print(decodedText)
else:
    print("QR code not detected")
```

I have to detect this particular image: [QR Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Guz.png)

The problem is that decodedText is empty and nothing is shown and the program doesn't go in else part.

**NOTE:** The QR code is detected fine from my mobile camera but not through this program.

Comment: Are you sure that the image is loaded properly?

Comment: Yes the picture is loaded. decodedText is empty, while points variable contains the point that are detected from QR image.

Comment: @Miki I have the exact same issue